# Android - Send Telegram message to a specific number

Tags: java, android, telegram

I'm trying to send a Telegram message to a specific number from within my Android app. Right now my code launches Telegram app, and then the user has to select the destinatary. What I want to do is to send the message to the specified number, without having the user select the contact. My code is as follows:

```
/**
 * Intent to send a telegram message
 * @param msg
 */
void intentMessageTelegram(String msg)
{
    final String appName = "org.telegram.messenger";
    final boolean isAppInstalled = isAppAvailable(mUIActivity.getApplicationContext(), appName);
    if (isAppInstalled) 
    {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        myIntent.setType("text/plain");
        myIntent.setPackage(appName);
        myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, msg);//
        mUIActivity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(myIntent, "Share with"));
    } 
    else 
    {
        Toast.makeText(mUIActivity, "Telegram not Installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I did something like that by using an `eMail` intent (it opens a chooser - Telegram is listed), which I can make the default, eventually. I also send optional attachments (0, 1 or 2 - depending on user choices). I use the recipient's `eMail address`.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that since Telegram uses your phone contact list and it doesn't have a _Type a new number to chat with_ function by itself

Comment: hi check my answer in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41777520/4336094)
question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Telegram Android App does not have a way to send messages directly to telegram users, so if you use the share intent, you'll get what telegram / any other app wants to do with the message shared. In this case, open the contact list to send this message to him.

If you want to send messages directly to Telegram users you should use the Telegram API
https://core.telegram.org/api#getting-started

once you have configured your API key in your app, you could send messages, read them or even get the telegram contacts with these methods

https://core.telegram.org/methods

Answer (score 11):

You can't send to special number, But You can do this by USERID

```
try {

    Intent telegramIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    telegramIntent.setData(Uri.parse("http://telegram.me/USERID"));
    startActivity(telegramIntent);

} catch (Exception e) {
        // show error message
}
```

This code will show user an alert for choosing applications that support telegram uri's like Telegram itself and Mobogram!

**Tip:** don't set package name. some people install telegram alternatives like mobogram.

Comment: How can i get username of user?

Answer (score 2):

**This one worked for me:**

```
    try {
    Intent telegram = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://t.me/USER_NAME"));
     telegram.setPackage("org.telegram.messenger");
     startActivity(telegram);
    }catch (Exception e) 
    {
       Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Telegram app is not installed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
```

**Tip:** You can get USER_NAME by click on you telegram profile option you will get option of username in Account session --> if username is none create unique username and put here its work for me.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me:

//check if application is installed first before running this code.

```
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse("http://telegram.me/+UT_USER_ID_HERE"));
            final String appName = "org.telegram.messenger";
                    i.setPackage(appName);
            this.startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

try the intent like this
tg://resolve?domain=YOUR_USER_ID
it's more direct then https://t.me

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this for send message on background :
this cod is api telegram for use send message by url token bot

1 - use WebView on xml like this :

```
    <WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView_sendToTelegram"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"/>
```

2 - on java use this cod:

```
public static void SendMessageToBotTelegram(String chatID, String text, String botToken,WebView webView) {
    webView.loadUrl(MessageFormat.format("https://api.telegram.org/bot{0}/sendMessage?chat_id={1}&text={2}", botToken, chatID, text));
}
```

chatID : your telegram id @RawDataBot for get id  
text : text your message 
botToken : your bot for get message if you don't have bot using @BotFather for crate bot 
webView : your id WebView on xml