# Open telegram channel in android

Tags: android, telegram

In my app  want to use `Intent` to open specific telegram channel or telegram group. i search in SF but i can't find anything.i try to implement but i only can open all messenger apps that user can choose but not telegram or specific telegram group or channel. if find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30055201/android-send-telegram-message-to-a-specific-number) on sf but it's not answer to my question.

```
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    myIntent.setType("text/plain");
    myIntent.setPackage(appName);
    myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, msg);//
    mUIActivity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(myIntent, "Share with"));
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Intent for opening a Telegram channel or user :

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("tg://resolve?domain=partsilicon"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: also we can use `http://www.telegram.me/groupname` in intent and when user click on button can choose telegram

Comment: can we add message or text on this link?

Comment: add try catch for above solution. Otherwise app will crash if telegram app not installed

Answer (score 6):

First check if any telegram client (telegram messenger or telegram x) is installed. If not open it in browser.

```
fun telegramIntent(context: Context): Intent {
    var intent: Intent? = null
    try {
        try {
           context.packageManager.getPackageInfo("org.telegram.messenger", 0)//Check for Telegram Messenger App
        } catch (e : Exception){
           context.packageManager.getPackageInfo("org.thunderdog.challegram", 0)//Check for Telegram X App
        }
       intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("tg://resolve?domain=${TELEGRAM_PAGE_ID}"))
    }catch (e : Exception){ //App not found open in browser
       intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.telegram.me/$TELEGRAM_PAGE_ID"))
    }
   return intent!!
}
```

Comment: The ```${TELEGRAM_PAGE_ID}"```it could be a phone number or what it should be??

Comment: ${TELEGRAM_PAGE_ID} that is nothing but the group id/channel id which we are trying to open. To locate the channel id, open any telegram channel, click on the channel info. You will find a link e.g `https://t.me/easyoffers` the  ${TELEGRAM_PAGE_ID} would be `easyoffers`

Comment: And if you want to open a conversation, not a group, the ${TELEGRAM_PAGE_ID}  will be the phone number??

Answer (score 5):

Answer @Saurabh Padwekar is good, but i want tell that you probably [need add queries for Android SDK 30+](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility) like this:

```
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="tg" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

Answer (score 2):

Java version of @Saurabh Padwekar 's answer!

```
  Intent getTelegramInt(Context context) {
        Intent intent;
        try {
            try { // check for telegram app
                context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("org.telegram.messenger", 0);
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                // check for telegram X app
                context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("org.thunderdog.challegram", 0);
            }
            // set app Uri
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("tg://resolve?domain=${TELEGRAM_PAGE_ID}"));
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            // set browser URI
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.telegram.me/$TELEGRAM_PAGE_ID"));
        }
        return intent;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private void getTelegramInt(Context context) {

    Intent intent;

    try {
        try {
            context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("org.telegram.messenger", 0);
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("org.thunderdog.challegram", 0);
        }
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("tg://resolve?domain=dilshod_software"));
        startActivity(intent);

    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://t.me/dilshod_software"));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

My button click :
telegram_image.setOnClickListener(view1 -> getTelegramInt(this));

Comment: Whats the logic behind returning the intent?

Answer (score 1):

This would be a more complete answer:

```
try {
     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(telegramLink));
     PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
     if (intent.resolveActivity(pm) != null) {
          startActivity(intent);
     } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Error message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }
```