# How to Open Mobile Telegram client

Tags: android

Is it possible to open mobile Telegram client with link?
For example

```
imgVk.setOnClickListener(new OpenLinkListener(getActivity(), "vk.com/id23**36*35"));
```

is opening userpage in mobile Vk client.

But,

```
imgTelegramMe.setOnClickListener(new OpenLinkListener(getActivity(), "web.telegram.org/#/im?p=@Artem_NeFRiT"));
```

is not working... It just opens the web browser...

**EDIT**

```
imgTelegramMe.setOnClickListener(new OpenLinkListener(getActivity(), "telegram.org/#/im?p=@Artem_NeFRiT"));
```

doesn't work too

**SOLUTION**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("tg://resolve?domain=Artem_NeFRiT"));
            startActivity(intent);
```

but u have to check for ActivityNotFoundException if there is no mobile Telegram client.

Comment: Whether the link opens in an app or in the browser is determined by whether the target app supports it or not. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525063/android-respond-to-url-in-intent

Comment: Yes, thanks, I know that. 
But I don't know, does Telegram client support that?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34692116/open-telegram-channel-in-android

Comment: Sorry, It seems that I am so blind...
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("tg://resolve?domain=Artem_NeFRiT"));
startActivity(intent);
works perfectly with Telegram client